# very unsafe behavior of extract() and compact() function with non standard variables, it is a bug or a feature ;)?

Tags: php

Not everyone knows that php can handle variables that have first characters as numbers, spaces, or other special language reserved words and characters in it. And it seems for whoever coded extract function this esoteric knowledge was not known..

```
${0} = 'bug';

$array = array('some value','some other value');
extract($array); // //no error code is returned whatsoever

echo ${0}; // returns 'bug'
echo ${1}; //Notice: Undefined variable 1 in...
```

ok, let's do the other way around:

```
$array = compact(0); // no error...
print_r($array); // Array() - no seriously, what the...
```

This is **MADNESS** !! It can lead to serious and hard to spot errors in code. Moreover, script could run as happy as nothing happened until you see with your paleface that something in the output is completely messed.

Comment: Since `0 !== 'zero'`, I'm unsure exactly what the problem is.  And `extract()`/`compact()` are already unsafe if you use them with untrusted data.

Comment: Not really sure why a function doing nothing (as documented) is "unsafe".

Comment: belongs on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ Q&A for expert programmers interested in professional discussions on software development

Comment: so please move it there, is there a button for me where I could do it myself ?

Comment: Unfortunately no, there isn't. We need to wait for moderators to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is open source. Feel free to contribute a patch to fix this behavior if you feel it should be fixed and/or join the [PHP mailing list](http://news.php.net/group.php?group=php.internals) to discuss this topic with other PHP developers.

Simply ranting is pointless, especially here.

Comment: Well, this is a place for such questions anyway.

Comment: Actually I think thise evloved into something that would fit Programmers.SE better

Comment: @rsk82: Pardon, but apart from the subject there is no question in your post. For me this sounds like you found out about some behavior you don't like and decided to tell us. Which is okay in general, but I guess there are more appropriate places for this kind of discussion. IMO.

Comment: only if php's mailing lists have a nice http gateway...

Answer (score 4):

To answer your question, you should better read the documentation of the [`extract`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) function:

> An associative array. This function treats keys as variable names and values as variable values. For each key/value pair it will create a variable in the current symbol table, subject to extract_type and prefix parameters.
>   You must use an associative array; **a numerically indexed array will not produce results** [highlight by me] unless you use EXTR_PREFIX_ALL or EXTR_PREFIX_INVALID.

And even earlier:

> Checks each key to see whether it has a **valid** [highlight by me] variable name.

Even you can specify a variable with an invalid label via the curly brackets syntax, it does not mean, it's a valid label (hence the curly braces, you can't w/o). This function is making use of valid variable labels only which are defined in the manual here: [Variables Basics<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php)

**Edit:** For sure, `extract` treats variables in curly brackets as names: [Demo](http://codepad.org/cvhdQxrq). It's just that you don't understand why there is something like a valid variable label (hence `0` or `0000` or `{0}` are not used in extraction). You might be more looking for an array instead of a variable. Use the language as a tool. Not your expectations. It's not a fault of the language if it doesn't meet your expectations.

**Edit2:** As it looks like you never give up running in the wrong direction, gladly PHP has [terms and conditions](http://php.net/license/index.php) you make use of:

```
THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE PHP DEVELOPMENT TEAM ``AS IS'' AND 
ANY EXPRESSED OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO,
THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A 
PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED.  IN NO EVENT SHALL THE PHP
DEVELOPMENT TEAM OR ITS CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, 
INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES 
(INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR 
SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION)
HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT,
STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE)
ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED
OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
```

How can you say that extract should do like you expect? Especially as what you are concerned about is defined behavior even. Look into the source, it's all written in there. Show us where the "huge bug" is within the implementation and I'm sure this will become more productive.

Comment: And this is a huge bug, if numerical array won't produce results, there should be a warning thrown up and script should stop executing, and there should be flag EXTR_NONSTANDARD_VARIABLES to supress this error.

Comment: @rsk82: You should better read the manual. If it doesn't help you, go nuts about it, but please don't take this site with you :)

Comment: Can you show me a variable that is specified by curly braces and is also invalid ?

Comment: You can't express a variable with curly braces that contains curly braces itself, like `${{0}}`. [Demo](http://codepad.org/mQ3Dctln). BTW the convention by `extract` is to not use the `$` sign which is normally part of the variable label as well. So you could moan about that as well. You need to differ between the language which get's evaluated and the convention anyway.

Comment: Sorry but I won't moan, since it is allowed: `${'{yes we can}'} = 'barack obama'; echo ${'{yes we can}'};` try it. And `${{0}} = 'no we cannot';` will give a parse error, so everything is ok here. Secondly, `$` is not part of a variable, it is simple indicator that this is variable $var === ${'var'}.

Comment: Yes it is allowed, just like driving a car on railroad tracks. Just don't complain when there's a train ahead

Comment: I don't know of any country or state where driving car on railroad is legal, well maybe in Nevada... (Yes totally off topic I know.)

Comment: `$('{0}') !== ${0}` - these are two totally different variables. (response for a comment that was deleted)

Comment: @rsk82: You need to differ between the concept of a variable name and the implementation in the language. By default `0` as a variable name is invalid. Using curly braces syntax was not meant to fully support invalid variable names in all directions, but to have a work-around in certain cases. It does not mean it works always, it just works in certain cases. It's okay that `extract` only handles valid variable names. It's not a bug. It's just okay. Just don't use curly braces if you have a problem to understand for what they are for.

Comment: @rsk82: `$('{0}')` is syntax error. What should that be? Please express :)

Comment: My mistake, it should be `${'{0}'}` of course, I can't edit my previous comment. Too much jquery I guess.

Comment: @rsk82: All those are invalid variable names, that's why you need to use the curly brackets within the language (to not get a syntax error). Extract however, won't let these pass (as written, for a good reason). If you're just concerned how to extract an array with such keys: http://codepad.org/CWcBjb4s  - You should just be clear about what you're doing.

Comment: `${0} === ${'0'}` creating array with string numerals in this context produces even more unpredicability. Because also `array(0=>'sth')===array('0'=>'sth')`

Comment: Are you referring to something like `${0}{0}{0} = 'A';`? I think it's a flaw with substr access, but only on empty strings. Which can make sense, as PHP is loosely typed. So better know your language in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

In PHP variables must start with unsderscore or a letter. If you use `{}` to cleverly go around this, what you get is what C programmers call 'undefined behaviour'. Don't call it madness, when it's you who abuses the language.

Comment: How can I abuse the language if it allows me to do so. Was that hard to add error exception for compact and extract, they just didn't thought about it. I know that these functions are unsafe, but what is the reason for making them even more unsafe ?

Comment: These functions work as intended with variable names that are valid PHP variable names. When you use them outside of their intended scope, you get into situation, where you can get different results in PHP5.3, different in PHP5.4 and different in PHP5.5. You go there on your own risk. Want to be safe - stay on the safe path.

Comment: @rsk The extract and compact functions follow the PHP specifications regarding variable names. The curly-brackets hack is the hack here.

Comment: Moreover I see nothing wrong with using non standard variables, referring to them is concise and they are used as every other ordinary variable. That is just convention, and sometimes it is very convenient to have space in the variable name similar to having space in array key name.

Comment: Sure it might be convienient and it's good to have them when parsing JSON to object for example, but as you can see it can lead to unexpected behaviour. You should avoid such variable names, because these are not valid PHP variable names. <-- period

Comment: If there are not valid why are then allowed ? How can be allowed something that is not valid ?

Comment: It is not allowed. It is undocumented. If you find in troublesome bring it to bugs.php.net

Comment: So it is a documentantion error.

Comment: If you find in troublesome bring it to bugs.php.net You can report documentation errors there as well. And while you're at it please write to GM to complain their manuals say nothing about cars not  being able to drive under water (I'll drop the railroad analogy ;P )

Answer (score 3):

Your compact example works if you pass it as a string IE: `compact('0');`

The example with `extract` makes sense because the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) says that it "Checks each key to see whether it has a valid variable name.", and 0 and 1 are not valid variable names.

A valid PHP variable name matches this regex: `[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*` Obviously a variable begining with a number is invalid.

**Edit**

Just for fun, try to trace the following function I just wrote which computes `$x % $m` using invalid variable variables:

```
function mod($x, $m){
    ${'$'} = '$';
    for($i = 0; $i < $m; $i++)
        ${'$'} = ${${'$'}} = ${'$'}.'$';
    ${${'$'}} = '$$';
    for($i = 0; $i <= abs($x); $i++)
        ${'$'} = ${${'$'}};
    for($i = 2; ${'$'}{$i}; $i++);
    return $i-2;
}
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck is bettah.